# merging filter multiple condition on pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

Here's my dataset `sparkDF1`

```
Id   Value  month   Year
1    672        4   2020  
1    356        6   2020
2    683        6   2019  
3    366        4   2021
```

Here's my dataset `sparkDF2`

```
Id   Value  month   Year
1    671        4   2020  
1    353        6   2020
2    682        6   2019  
3    363        4   2021
```

Here's my expected dataset `sparkDF` that is used `sparkDF2` from month=5 Year=2020 and before that using `sparkDF1`

```
Id   Value  month   Year
1    672        4   2020  
1    353        6   2020
2    683        6   2019  
3    363        4   2021
```

The pandas alternative is

```
df = df1.mask((df1['month'].ge(5) & df1['Year'].eq(2020)) | df1['Year'].ge(2021), df2)
```

Comment: sorry typo, its two different dataset, the first dataset more valid before month=5 Year=2020, and the other is more valid after month=5 Year=2020

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1:    Filter and unionBy

```
s=((df1.month >= 5)&(df1.Year == 2020))|(df1.Year >= 2021)

s1=((df2.month >= 5)&(df2.Year == 2020))|(df2.Year >= 2021)

new = df1.where(~s).unionByName(df2.where(s1)).orderBy('Id')

new.show()

+---+-----+-----+----+
| Id|Value|month|Year|
+---+-----+-----+----+
|  1|  672|    4|2020|
|  1|  353|    6|2020|
|  2|  683|    6|2019|
|  3|  363|    4|2021|
+---+-----+-----+----+
```

Option 2: If you have pandas code, you can use pandas udfs. The problem with pandas udf that include two dataframes use the `cogroup` method which incurs a shuffle. In your case. I would use pandas' `combine_first` or **just what you did**. code below

import pandas as pd

```
def mask_filter(l: pd.DataFrame, r: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
  l =l.mask((l['month'].ge(5) & l['Year'].eq(2020)) | l['Year'].ge(2021))
  r=r
  return l.combine_first(r)

df1.groupBy(['month', 'Year']).cogroup(df2.groupBy(['month', 'Year'])).applyInPandas(mask_filter, schema=df2.schema).orderBy('Id').show()
```

or

```
import pandas as pd

def mask_filter(l: pd.DataFrame, r: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
  t =l.mask((l['month'].ge(5) & l['Year'].eq(2020)) | l['Year'].ge(2021),r)
  
  return t

df1.groupBy(['month', 'Year']).cogroup(df2.groupBy(['month', 'Year'])).applyInPandas(mask_filter, schema=df2.schema).orderBy('Id').show() 
+---+-----+-----+----+
| Id|Value|month|Year|
+---+-----+-----+----+
|  1|  672|    4|2020|
|  3|  363|    4|2021|
|  2|  683|    6|2019|
|  1|  353|    6|2020|
+---+-----+-----+----+
```

Answer (score 1):

you can filter each df on its own and then union the two. Alternatively you can use [Koalas](https://koalas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#) which will give you pandas syntax on spark

Comment: koalas is getting deprecated. Use pandas udfs  https://docs.databricks.com/languages/koalas.html#:~:text=Koalas%20is%20useful%20not%20only%20for%20pandas%20users,clusters%20running%20Databricks%20Runtime%207.3%20and%20above.%20

Comment: @wwnde it is being merged to Spark https://docs.databricks.com/languages/pandas-spark.html . Anyway, I wouldn't use pandas UDFs for this and this will do the merge outside of spark whereas koalas/spark pandas API - is compiled to spark code

Comment: ok, good to hear @Arnon Rotem-Gal-Oz. I must have misread it. Not used Koalas before. Would be intereting to see a koalas option and see how it compares in terms of compute resource. Thanks a million for this!